# Wpf MVVM Load UI control asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, asynchronous

I have a mvvm wpf application that loads up a window consisting of many controls in one go. I want this window to load up the controls separately and asynchronously.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For that matter, I use a Singleton pattern. If you're familiar with PRISM and its Bootstrapper, it is kinda similar.

The main idea here is to override the method `OnStartup` in your App.xaml. Default behavior shows in your xaml `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`, you'll have to remove that property.

In the `OnStartup` override method, I use a class which creates all my objects (Views, ViewModels, link DataContexts... ) and fires an event when initialization is complete.

At this time I dismiss the splashscreen and show a fully loaded app (the `InitializeComponent` is called when you create your `MainWindow`, so it'll be already called at this time).

For more extended use, you can add events in your windows and `EventHandler`s in your bootstrapper class. I use it for example when I want to fully refresh my app (reboot it), and also for database requests (which are, in my case, performed only on application startup to load the referential).

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your controls are defined in XAML, they're going to be initialized with the InitializeComponent call and go through the loading process.  All of the events in loading a XAML window happen whether or not you subscribe to them.

You could add controls dynamically to the form in code behind, but if you have a separate thread do the work, you would need to use the Application Dispatcher CheckAccess and Invoke methods to ensure the controls are loaded on the thread which owns them.